# Running two huggingface models on two gpus - parallel

Tags: multithreading, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use 2 gpus, loading one model on each gpu to make an inference (half of the images on gpu0, the other half on gpu2). I have tried the following code but it returns an error stating `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'run_inference_parallel.<locals>.<lambda>'`. Any guidance on how to fix the code would be appreciated

```py
from PIL import Image
from transformers import Pix2StructProcessor, Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration

from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm

import torch
import os, multiprocessing, subprocess

# Load and initialize models on separate GPUs
path_1 = "../Deplot/deplot_models/warmup4_deplot/"
processor_1 = Pix2StructProcessor.from_pretrained(path_1, is_vqa=True)
model_1 = Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(path_1, is_vqa=True).to('cuda:0')  # Load model onto GPU 0

path_2 = "../Deplot/deplot_models/warmup4_deplot/"
processor_2 = Pix2StructProcessor.from_pretrained(path_2, is_vqa=True)
model_2 = Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(path_2, is_vqa=True).to('cuda:2')  # Load model onto GPU 2

# Input data for inference
input_imgs = glob('../Deplot/test/images/*')

# Function to perform inference on a model
def infer_on_model(processor, model, test_pics_path):
    test_pics = [Image.open(f).convert("RGB") for f in test_pics_path]
    
    inputs = processor(
        images=test_pics,
        text=["Generate underlying data table of the figure below:"] * len(test_pics),
        return_tensors="pt",
    ).to(device)
    
    predictions = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=512)
    
    for i, (prediction, test_pic_path) in enumerate(zip(predictions, test_pics_path)):
        deplot_result = processor.decode(prediction, skip_special_tokens=True)
        print(deplot_result)
#         with open(f'./Validations/val_{model_name}/{test_pic_path.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]}.txt', 'w+') as f:
#             f.write(deplot_result)

# Run inference in parallel using multiprocessing
def run_inference_parallel(input_imgs):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)  # Number of processes (1 per GPU)

    # Define partial functions for each model
    partial_func_model1 = lambda x: infer_on_model(processor_1, model_1, x)
    partial_func_model2 = lambda x: infer_on_model(processor_2, model_2, x)

    # Run inference in parallel for each model
    pool.map(partial_func_model1, input_imgs[:len(input_imgs)//2])
    pool.map(partial_func_model2, input_imgs[len(input_imgs)//2:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_inference_parallel(input_imgs)
```